# Wordpress - Custom Menu on Post pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to load a specific menu (that exists in Wordpress Menus) on pages that are "post".

Here is my current code (functions.php):

```
add_action('get_header', 'replace_post_menu');
function replace_post_menu() {
    if (is_singular('post')) {
        wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'New Menu' ));
    }
}
```

The problem is the menu is loading at the very top (above my current menu). I'm using the theme "Avada" (last version).

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a specific menu in the posts and a common menu for all other pages, do the following.

```
1. Replace the below code with your code in header.php.

<?php
    if (! is_singular('post')) {
        wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => '{enter the name of your common menu here}' ));
    }
?>

2. Keep your existing code in functions.php.
```